# How to predict the best value for the proportion of outliers?

Tags: scikit-learn, data-science, anomaly-detection

I'm using "Local Outlier Factor" for anomaly detection. The algorithm has a parameter called "**contamination**". This parameter represents the proportion of outliers. In my case, **"0.0058"** is the best value for the contamination parameter.

```
#parameters
n_neighbors = 750
p = 7
contamination = 0.0058 # the proportion of outliers 

lof = LocalOutlierFactor(n_neighbors=n_neighbors, p=p, contamination=contamination)
y_pred_train = lof.fit_predict(data_scaled)
```

I found this value after trying many different values. However, I need to find the best value for contamination parameter without trying different values.

Here is the shape of the data:

[image]

I have two questions;

Is it possible to predict the best value of contamination parameter before executing the anomaly detection algorithm?

In real world applications, is it possible for an anomaly detection model to detect all anomalies perfectly?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Local Outlier Factor value is a commonly used anomaly detection tool. It takes a local approach to better detect outliers about their neighbors, whereas a global strategy, might not be the best detection for datasets that fluctuate in density.

It totally depends on your dataset:

**Do you have a tight, clean, and uniform dataset?** Then a LOF value of 1.05 could be an outlier.

**Do you have a sparse dataset, varying in density, with many local fluctuations specific to that local cluster?** Then a LOF value of 2 could still be an inlier.